# String convert to timestamp in @Query using Spring Data JPA and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I would like to get from Postgresql all records before chosen date. Date is String. In my opinion the easiest way is to convert string into timestamp using to_timestamp.

```
select * from workers where update_date < to_timestamp('2018-08-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone;
```

I created method in my repository like bellow but it doesn't work.

```
@Query("select w from Worker w where w.update_date < to_timestamp(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone") 
List<Worker> findBeforeDate(@Param("date") String date);
```

It throws

> `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException`:
>   unexpected token: : near line 1, column 104 [`select w from com.oksa.workreport.doma.Worker w where w.update_date < to_timestamp(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone]`

Could anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: you can use native query `@Query("select * from workers where update_date < to_timestamp('2018-08-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone", nativeQuery="true")`

Comment: `@Query(value = "select * from workers where update_date < to_timestamp('2018-08-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone", nativeQuery=true)` I have to add value and remove quotation marks for true. Anyway stil have problems because I pass parameters there (date) and it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to escape the colons in your query. Try below:

```
@Query(value = "select w from Worker w where w.update_date < to_timestamp(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')\\:\\:timestamp without time zone", nativeQuery=true) 
List<Worker> findBeforeDate(@Param("date") String date);
```

Comment: It works. At the same time I create another solution: `@Query(value="select w from Worker w where w.update_date < CAST (:date as timestamp without time zone) order by update_date", 
   nativeQuery = true)
 List<Worker> findBeforeDate(@Param("date") String date);` I use CAST instead of to_timestamp

Comment: By the way you have to use **value** before **select**

Comment: Yes, my bad. Updated the answer.